# Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App without user login

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-b2c

I have a situation like this

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi

but I want the asp.net web app to be able to call Web Api without user access, I want Web App authentication to be performed only through ClientId and ClientSecret. 
It's possible ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Users will expect to see some of the code you have already tried so we can help you debug.  Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

> but I want the asp.net web app to be able to call Web Api without user
>   access, I want Web App authentication to be performed only through
>   ClientId and ClientSecret. It's possible ?

As far as I know, that's impossible in the B2C. In the B2C, all the policies are related to the user operation, there is no way to get the app-only token. If you want the non-interaction with user flow, the ROPC could be used in the B2C.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure AD B2C doesn't support the client credentials flow, which is required for the machine-to-machine authentication.

You can, however, configure [the client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) using the Azure AD functionality of the Azure AD B2C tenant.

See [the "Current limitations" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#daemonsserver-side-applications) for more information.

Comment: The code samples are listed at [the bottom of the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#code-samples-and-other-documentation).